# Multiple column in single case in order by clause in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I wrote a query in which I have a condition to sort the data by multiple columns in single order by like below.

```
ORDER BY Column1 ASC, Column2 ASC, Column3 ASC
```

or

```
ORDER BY Column1 DESC, Column2 DESC, Column3 DESC
```

I want to write above kind of sorting in conditional order by expression like below

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Id ASC' THEN Id END ASC,    
    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Id DESC' THEN Id END DESC,    
    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Status ASC' THEN Status END ASC,    
    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Status DESC' THEN Status END DESC,   
    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Country ASC' THEN Country Asc, City Asc, Zip Asc END,    
    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Country DESC' THEN Country DESC, City DESC, Zip DESC END
```

but above query gives syntax error. Can anyone help me to find out the solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a syntax for   `CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Country ASC' THEN Country Asc, City Asc, Zip Asc END,`  you need to write let each order in a `CASE WHEN`.

if `@SortExpression` only will set one value. if the `CASE WHEN` didn't match the condition will return `NULL` then let will only execute your expect order columns.

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Id ASC' THEN Id END ASC,    
    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Id DESC' THEN Id END DESC,    
    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Status ASC' THEN Status END ASC,    
    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Status DESC' THEN Status END DESC,   
    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Country ASC' THEN Country END Asc ,
    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Country ASC' THEN City END Asc ,
    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Country ASC' THEN Zip END Asc ,   
    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Country DESC' THEN Country END DESC , 
    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Country DESC' THEN City END DESC , 
    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Country DESC' THEN Zip END DESC
```

Comment: your answer and above to yours are same and worked well for me....which one to mark for answer is really hard for me. Anyways thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your case statement need re-write below way, you written multiple column after then `(THEN Country Asc, City Asc, Zip Asc END)` which is incorrect

```
ORDER BY 
(CASE @SortExpression  when 'Id ASC'
 THEN Id End) ASC,    
(CASE @SortExpression WHEN 'Id DESC'
THEN Id END) DESC,    
(CASE @SortExpression 
WHEN 'Status ASC' 
THEN Status END ) ASC,    
(CASE @SortExpression WHEN 'Status DESC'
 THEN Status END) DESC,   
(CASE @SortExpression WHEN 'Country ASC' 
THEN Country end) Asc,
(CASE @SortExpression WHEN 'Country ASC' 
THEN City end) Asc,
(CASE @SortExpression WHEN 'Country ASC' 
THEN Zip end) Asc,         
( CASE @SortExpression  WHEN 'Country DESC'
THEN Country end ) DESC ,
( CASE @SortExpression  WHEN 'Country DESC'
THEN City end ) DESC,
( CASE @SortExpression  WHEN 'Country DESC'
THEN Zip end ) DESC
```

Comment: your answer and below to yours are same and worked well for me....which one to mark for answer is really hard for me. Anyways thanks a lot. :)